# Unable to Connect S3 Bucket with Route 53 for Domain Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm having trouble connecting my S3 bucket with Route 53. The bucket works with its URL, but when I add the domain through Route 53, it doesn't work. I'm attaching images with the configurations:

Hosts statis web:

[image: hosts statis web]

Bucket Policy:
[image: bucket policy]

Domain Route 53:
[image: domain route53]

I have also tried using the 'www' domain.

Thank you

I have tried deleting the bucket multiple times, which currently hosts an Angular web application, and I have also tried adding a basic HTML, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)? (You don't need two buckets, but it shows the general steps.)

Comment: Are you saying that it works when you use the `s3-website.eu-west-amazon...` DNS name, but doesn't work when you use your `.info` DNS name? What happens if you try to resolve your DNS name (eg use it with `ping yourdomain.info`) -- does it resolve to an IP address?

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, but what about using CloudFront  CDN to front the S3 bucket (setting the S3 bucket as an CloudFront Origin) and then linking CloudFront to R53 as an A record?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was

"During the process of transferring a domain registration to Route 53, you get the option to choose the name servers that you want to use. It appears that you chose to use name servers from registrar-servers.com rather than the name servers for your Route 53 hosted zone. Even if you have a Route 53 hosted zone when you transfer a domain to Route 53, we don't assume that you want to use that hosted zone."

I write the same name servers and it works!